# Protractor tests fails because model value is empty

Tags: angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, integration-testing, protractor

I have a sample [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/yfUQ8/9/edit/) that I am trying to test using protractor.

Below are my tests

```
describe("Fiddle homepage", function() {


    beforeEach(function() {
        browser.get('http://fiddle.jshell.net/yfUQ8/9/show');
        browser.rootEl = 'div';
    });
    describe("binding", function() {
        var inputByModel;
        beforeEach(function() {
            inputByModel = element(by.model('model.yourName'));
        })
        // Fail
        it("should have value Julie1", function() {
            inputByModel.sendKeys('Julie1');
            // browser.waitForAngular();
            expect(inputByModel.getText()).to.eventually.equal('Julie1');

        });
        // Fail
        it("should have value Julie2", function() {
            inputByModel.sendKeys('Julie2');

            var greeting = element(by.model('model.yourName'));
            expect(greeting.getText()).to.eventually.equal('Julie2');
        });
        // Pass
        it("should have value Julie3", function() {
            inputByModel.sendKeys('Julie3');
            var byBinding = element(by.binding('model.yourName'));
            expect(byBinding.getText()).to.eventually.equal('Julie');
        });
        // Fail
        it("should get value by id and should pass the test", function() {
            inputByModel.sendKeys('Julie4');

            var byID = element(by.id('myinput'));
            expect(byID.getText()).to.eventually.equal('Julie4');
        })
    });
});
```

I am using mocha, chaiAsPromised to run my tests. Can anyone explain why my first two tests are failing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get the text of an input element, you have to use:

```
getAttribute('value')
```

instead of

```
getText()
```

This is documented in the Protractor FAQ:  https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/faq.md#the-result-of-gettext-from-an-input-element-is-always-empty

Comment: Hmm that did work! Wonder why is it part of FAQ and not mentioned in the examples or at least I could not find one. Thanks anyways!